# VS Code not to use the real path of a symlink

Tags: visual-studio-code, symlink

I have a bunch of directories that are symlinks to the real directory on another hard disk.

Visual Studio Code insists on showing me the real path that I do not want to see. It shows me that instead of the symlink where I open my projects from. (In my opinion this behaviour is incorrect.)

For Example:

symlink: *c:\work\someproject*
real path: *d:\projects_for_blabla\2018\someproject*

Then I open folder "c:\work\someproject" and in the sidebar and on the tooltips all paths are "d:\projects_for_blabla\2018\someproject\file" instead of the wanted "c:\work\someproject\file".

Does anyone know how to force VSCode to respect the symlink and stop it from showing real paths?

UPDATE (adding screenshots):

This is how I want to see the project - in this case PhpProjects is a symlink:

[image]

And this is what happens in VS Code:

[image]

Opened is one and the same file - the editor shows it to me twice because the first time I opened it directly from Explorer (via c:\..) and the second time is when I press Ctrl+P

And here is what I see them when I press Ctrl+P:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the screenshot, where it shows the path?

Comment: @YashuMittal I added screenshots

Comment: I'd like to tell VS Code to open the original file too. It's annoying.